# Drupal database doesn't work after MySQL restart

Tags: mysql, innodb, drupal

I've installed Drupal 7x on my local XAMPP 1.8.3 Server. Everything went fine but after adding some modules, changing the drupal theme and restarting the MySQL Server, the MySQL Server is dropping some errors and stopped working.

*mysql_error.log*

> 2013-09-02 16:18:46 2544 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
>
> 2013-09-02 16:18:46 3e8 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
>
> 2013-09-02 16:18:46 2544 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
>
> 2013-09-02 16:18:46 2544 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
>
> 2013-09-02 16:18:46 2544 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
>
> 2013-09-02 16:18:46 2544 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
>
> 2013-09-02 16:18:46 2544 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
>
> 2013-09-02 16:18:46 2544 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
>
> 2013-09-02 16:18:46 2544 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
>
> 2013-09-02 16:18:47 2544 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 1600614 and 1600614 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 1600644 in the ib_logfiles!
>
> 2013-09-02 16:18:47 2544 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
>
> 2013-09-02 16:18:47 2544 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
>
> 2013-09-02 16:18:47 2544 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
>
> 2013-09-02 16:18:47 2544 [ERROR] InnoDB: Attempted to open a previously opened tablespace. Previous tablespace drupal/variable uses space ID: 2 at filepath: .\drupal\variable.ibd. Cannot open tablespace mysql/innodb_index_stats which uses space ID: 2 at filepath: .\mysql\innodb_index_stats.ibd
>
> InnoDB: Error: could not open single-table tablespace file .\mysql\innodb_index_stats.ibd
>
> InnoDB: We do not continue the crash recovery, because the table may become
>
> InnoDB: corrupt if we cannot apply the log records in the InnoDB log to it.
>
> InnoDB: To fix the problem and start mysqld:
>
> InnoDB: 1) If there is a permission problem in the file and mysqld cannot
>
> InnoDB: open the file, you should modify the permissions.
>
> InnoDB: 2) If the table is not needed, or you can restore it from a backup,
>
> InnoDB: then you can remove the .ibd file, and InnoDB will do a normal
>
> InnoDB: crash recovery and ignore that table.
>
> InnoDB: 3) If the file system or the disk is broken, and you cannot remove
>
> InnoDB: the .ibd file, you can set innodb_force_recovery > 0 in my.cnf
>
> InnoDB: and force InnoDB to continue crash recovery here.

I tried to fix the problem with the solutions named above, but it didn't work. I've turned the UAC off (for point 1.: permission problem). Deleted the .idb File for point 2 and to point 3: I've looked everywhere for the my.cnf but couldn't find any. I don't know where to look for the problem/solution :( .

Comment: Ok, i think i got it. It was a problem with the user privilegs for the database. The user had the rights but after shutting down MySQL, the changes my user did, were all cancelled. Now my user has limited privileges only at this database and - behold - it works :).

Comment: For more information, please go to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18575755/xampp-mysql-could-not-open-single-table-tablespace-file-mysql-innodb-index-st